# Limit FluentNHibernate Query to Values in Distinct List?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Forgive my potentially novice question, I've done some searching and some toying around but I can't seem to produce the desired effect.

I want to replicate the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ItemNumber IN ('00012A', '0034B', 'AB097');
```

I have a distinct list of items that I want to limit my query to, but it is generating the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

Below is the method I'm using:

```
public IList<Item> GetItemList(List<String> distinctItemList)
{
    var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            return session.Query<Item>()
                .Where(x => distinctItemList.Any(y => y == x.ItemNumber)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?  I was originally successfully returning

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Item)).List<Item>();
```

..but I can't seem to modify this to allow for limiting clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being much easier than I initially thought:

```
return session.QueryOver<Item>()
      .Where(i => i.ItemNumber.IsIn(distinctItemList)).List();
```